# How should i use dependency injection when there are fields, not only methods

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am trying to understand dependency injector and it makes sense in my mind when the interface I am injecting has only methods. But what should I do when I have fields that need to have a specific value?

I know that after I make an instance of the class I can assign values like I did below but is that the right way?

```
interface IItem
{
    double Price { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    double Calories { get; set; }
    double Fats { get; set; }
    double Proteins { get; set; }
    double Sugars { get; set; }
    double Salt { get; set; }
}
class Item :  IItem
{
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double Calories { get; set; }
    public double Fats { get; set; }
    public double Proteins { get; set; }
    public double Sugars { get; set; }
    public double Salt { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class SomeClass
{
    public IItem _item;

    public SomeClass(ILabel label)
    {
         this._item = label;
    }
    public double SomeOperation()
    {
         return _item.Calories + _item.Fats + _item.Proteins; //just an example
    }
}

void main()
{
     IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
     container.RegisterType<IItem, Item>();

     SomeClass example = container.Resolve<SomeClass>();

     //what I know I can do but I don't think it's the right way
     example._item.Price = 100.0;
     example._item.Salt = 4;
     //you get it, how can I populate that the right way? and what if I have an array of "SomeClass" do I need to do that with every instance?

}
```

I expect to know how to populate the classes the right way. Thank you

Comment: No, this is not what dependency injection is about. It's about dependencies, not about data. Data is not a dependency. Do you instead want to load the data from an external resource, say a SQL database or JSON file?

Comment: We wouldn't typically use dependency injection to populate properties like this. Dependency injection selects dependencies at runtime or provides other environmental values that are configured at startup. But populating data like this isn't related to dependency injection.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish here.  (Or really what benefit DI or an interface even brings to this code.)  If you're trying to set values on properties, then setting values on properties is indeed exactly how you'd do that.  If you want your `Item` implementation to have default values, they can be set on that implementation (directly on the property declarations or in the constructor).

Comment: This is an exercise from my teacher and he asked us to use Unity or Ninject and i thought that i should use this for properties too. I didnt see any benefit either but i got it as an exercise. Thank you all, sorry for bothering

Comment: While I agree that you shouldn't use dependency injection for pure data classes, you really don't know if `IItem` will stay that way. In the future, someone might change the setter on `Name` to do a database lookup that you don't want to be dependent on. If the variables were fields rather than properties you could be sure that that would never happen. But that's a minor point and I wouldn't use DI for `IItem` myself.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency injection (DI) is about injecting functionality into other types.

A simple example would be to inject a logger.

```
class SomeClass
{
    public ILogger _logger;

    public SomeClass(ILogger logger)
    {
         this._logger = logger;
    }
    public double SomeOperation(IItem item)
    {
        _logger.Log("SomeOperation");
         return item.Calories + item.Fats + item.Proteins;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to specify the value of the property, you can use that (default values) :

```cs
class ItemWithSalt :  IItem
{
    public double Price { get; set; } = 100.0;
    public double Calories { get; set; }
    public double Fats { get; set; }
    public double Proteins { get; set; }
    public double Sugars { get; set; }
    public double Salt { get; set; } = 4.0;
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

but then it would make more sense to drop the setters and create Items like that :

```cs
interface IItem
{
    double Price { get;  }
    string Name { get;  }
    double Calories { get;  }
    double Fats { get;  }
    double Proteins { get;  }
    double Sugars { get;  }
    double Salt { get;  }
}

class SaltyItem: IItem
{
    public double Price => 100.00
    public double Salt => 4.0
    public string Name => "Salty";
}
class FattyItem: IItem
{
    public double Price => 100.00
    public double Fats => 4.0
    public string Name => "Fatty";
}
```

Comment: The question (and exercise, read the comments) is about dependency injection. Not necessarily about property assignment.